# Entering data into a structure with pointer member variables

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, cin, dot-operator

I'm having a bear of a time figuring out what to do next here. Basically, this program cannot use anything other than pointer variables (*) and dynamically assigned memory (e.g., "int *variable = new int"). I have to create a structure on top of everything else!

I've included some code below. There are red lines underneath all my cin ">>" operators and a message that says, "Error: No operator ">>" matches these operands". There is also a red line underneath my "one" in "one.score2" part of the code (last line) and a message that says, "Error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type".

How can I get my code to work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Define structures
struct student
{
    string *name;
    double *score, *score2, *average;
};

void main(void)
{
    // Create our students
    student one, two;

    cout << "Enter the first student's name: ";
    cin >> one.name;
    cout << endl << "Enter " << one.name << "'s first exam: ";
    cin >> one.score;
    cout << endl << "Enter " << one.name << "'s second exam: ";
    cin >> one.score2;
    one.average = ((one.score + one.score2) / 2);
```

Comment: Why would you have the members as pointers in the structure? This sounds like a contrived homework assignment.

Comment: You've answered your own question: "int *variable = new int" - where is that in your code?  You should actually create the string and doubles for one and two before you try to read something into them.

Comment: To fix your program you will want to look into: constructors, destructors, dynamic memory allocation and pointer dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use operator `*` to dereference the pointers. That is,

```
cout << "Enter the first student's name: ";
cin >> *one.name;
cout << endl << "Enter " << *one.name << "'s first exam: ";
cin >> *one.score;
cout << endl << "Enter " << *one.name << "'s second exam: ";
cin >> *one.score2;
*one.average = ((*one.score + *one.score2) / 2);
```

However, you need to remember to allocate memory for those pointers first.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your structure as below

```
struct student
{
    string name;
    double score, score2, average;
};
```

As per your example, they don't need to be pointers, as Joachim Pileborg also *points* out.

Answer (score 0):

The members like score are pointer to the actual data. E.g. `one.score` is a pointer to a double. When you want to cin to the double you should at least derefer the pointer:

```
cin >> *one.score
```

In your main() example you missed to allocate the data instance.

```
one.score = new int;
cin >> *one.score
```

The best way would avoid data accessed by pointers and make the data members of student.